# how to unselect all options in multiselect widget

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using jquery multiselect widget. I would like to uncheck all if all them were checked manually. I have a sample code in 
[JSFiddle--> Code](http://jsfiddle.net/fG6PT/8/)

This doesn't work. When the select options are selected manually, check for no of unchecked options in select it gives me 1 (at the click of last option) the first time. so I checked if `$this.children("option").not('[selected]').length`  is 1 and  `ui.checked`  and calling the `uncheckAll`
but after that it is behaving properly the code 
if `$this.children("option").not('[selected]').length`  gives me 0 when selecting the final one.

I am wondering what is happening.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, and the check/uncheck all in the fiddle works fine for me?

Comment: try selecting all of them manually. the multiselectclick event should get  triggered. if all of the options are selected then it should uncheckall which is not happening

Comment: it's working for me if I check them manually

Answer (score 14, accepted):

well so here is the solution what you want... check the **[documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)** , there is method `getChecked` to get `selected options`. yours is not working because the pluging reformat the select elements.

```
$('.multi').multiselect({
    click: function(e, ui){
    if($(this).multiselect("getChecked").length  
                              == $('select.multi > option').length){
       $(this).multiselect("uncheckAll");    
    }        
  }
});
```

**fiddle example :** http://jsfiddle.net/fG6PT/11/

Comment: This worked like charm. Note that this will work only for Jquery multiselect plugin

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#multiselectelement").multiselect("uncheckAll");
```